# If I host in the cloud, do I still need things like load balancing?

Tags: load-balancing, cloud-hosting

Just curious whether concepts like load-balancing are going away since cloud hosting seems to take care of such things for you?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: If you are using service like google-app-engine load-balancing, database(datastore) scaling etc. are all taken care of by the platform for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We run all of our servers in a cloud with Amazon.  We have a VPC setup and some of our servers sit behind a virtual load-balancer within Amazon.

The answer is that yes, you can still use such functionality.  Mostly it depends on how you use the cloud, what service you are with, and the load put on your systems.